# How to open a url in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a search text field with autocomplete. The autocomplete suggestions are the link and on hover it gets redirect to webpage. I was looking if there is a way to open url on same page in div below search text field(or any other way to open url on same page). 
Here is the js code

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
            source: [
                { value: "Imdb", url: 'http://www.imdb.com' },
                { value: "Macys", url: 'http://www.macys.com' },
                { value: "Verisign", url: 'http://www.verisign.com' },
                { value: "Chitown", url: 'http://www.chitown.com' },
                { value: "DC", url: 'http://www.washingtondc.com' },
                { value: "SF", url: 'http://www.sanfran.com' },
                { value: "Peru", url: 'http://www.peru.com' }
            ],
           // source: '/brands',
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                window.location = ui.item.url;
            }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Hint: AJAX or iframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an iFrame which you can dynamically insert wwith jQuery.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to load a page into a div.

```
// Replace .mydiv with the div class you want
$('.mydiv').load(ui.item.url);
```

Do keep in mind that you can't load stuff from a different domain due to the Same Origin Policy.